# Trying to Load Range into Array

Tags: excel, vba, validation

I have been trying to Load Range into Array but it does not work and no error is appear for specific range that is `G1:Z1` but it works for column. I really do not know why any help will be appreciated.

```
Sub LoadingData()

Dim sheet As Worksheet
Dim RangeArray As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim d As Object

Set sheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")

With sheet

    RangeArray = .Range("G1:Z1").Value
End With

Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

For i = LBound(RangeArray) To UBound(RangeArray)
    d(RangeArray(i, 1)) = 1
Next i

With Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C2").Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=Join(d.Keys, ",")
    .InCellDropdown = True
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Your code only sets dictionary keys for the first column of the range. Try using `d(RangeArray(1, i)) = 1`. The code should iterate between columns, since the row is only one...

Comment: I did, but it stills load first column value.

Comment: Please, replace `For i = LBound(RangeArray) To UBound(RangeArray)` with `For i = 1 To UBound(RangeArray, 2)`. `UBound(RangeArray, 2)` returns the array columns...

Comment: Works Perfect! please post this as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, replace:

```
For i = LBound(RangeArray) To UBound(RangeArray)
    d(RangeArray(i, 1)) = 1
Next i
```

with

```
For i = 1 To UBound(RangeArray, 2)
    d(RangeArray(1, i)) = 1
Next i
```

The code needs to iteratate between the range **columns**. `UBound(RangeArray)` returns the array number of rows, and you need `UBound(RangeArray, 2), which returns the number of columns.

Then, `i` must be moved to iterate between the array columns...

Comment: When i run the code and save the file it goes corrupted with this error: `“We found a problem with some content in ‘filename.xlsx’. Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes.` then i add in immediate window this `"? application.StartupPath"` and press enter and this result is  appear `expected : line number or label or statement or end of statement` @FaneDuru

Comment: @Valiant Such an error type, I think, should only be coming from the `Validation`, where I did not look at all... Please, try inserting `Debug.Print Join(d.Keys, ","): Stop`. What does it return in `Immediate Window`? Is there a space between the array elements, too? Try also inserting this line `.IgnoreBlank = True` in the `Validation` `Width`.

Comment: I got the problem when i use this range `RangeArray = .Range("A2:A100").Value` it works fine but when i use range `RangeArray = .Range("A2:A25000").Value` it gives the error `Run time error 1004 Application defined or object defined error` on this line `.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=Join(d.Keys, ",")`

Comment: @Valiant I think, the string cannot exceed a specific number of characters...

Comment: Is there any solution to fix that.

Comment: Please, try replacing the string with `=SheetName!A2:A25000`.

Comment: @Valiant Try using "=SheetName!A2:A25000"